# drush ne-import doesn't import field_tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, drush, importing-exporting

I'm using module node_export to migrate contents from my local to live. The content type has several fields with field_tags (multi-field term reference) being one. The exported file was created just fine. I tried exporting in xml, json and serialize, format and was able to search/find field_tags on each of the exported file. But when I ran `drush ne-import --file='exported_file'` the nodes were created without field_tags. Every other fields were created fine. I didn't see this on the bug report of node_export project page.

Comment: What version of Node export are you running ?

Comment: node_export version: 7.x-3.0
drush version: 7.31

Comment: Also is the `taxonomy` module enabled on the destination site?

Comment: This may be a known issue, https://www.drupal.org/node/1896384 . I rarely use this module due to similar issues I've found.

Comment: The taxonomy module is enabled, and the tags can be added manually, just not via node_export. I will continue watching the bug thread.